# Stream USB webcam with audio

Tags: streaming-video, webcam, vlc

I have a raspberry pi zero with a Logitech C920 webcam. I am hoping to do a video server (baby monitor) with these. I hope to use the H.264 encoding provided by the C920 and combine it with the audio stream and provide as a web site. As typically happens whenever I touch linux (https://xkcd.com/644/) things seem simple from the outset but implementation details get tricky.

I started off with Motion which was good at sending sequences of images, but it doesn't utilize the H.264 encoding and does not have audio.

I tried VLC streaming but only once got the video to work (but only accessed via VLC) but the configuration keeps getting jinxed. I get random segfaults and errors that don't explain anything.

I also have tried UV4L but can only get video working (on the :8080/stream destination, not sure if it is designed to not have audio).

Anyhow - most tutorials etc. are from 2012 or so. **Question:** is this something I should give up on or is there a program/system that I should look into more? I admit I'm pretty new to linux/rpi but I thought that one of the primary use cases for a rpi was as a security camera and I'm perplexed as to why I keep getting errors.

Comment: ' play or encode almost any video or audio ' https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=199775

Comment: I'll have to check that out! It definitely looks good! I'll come back and report.

Comment: It appears as though this is mainly for recieving and displaying and saving video streams. I'm looking for something that broadcasts streams. But it is a good place for me to start.  Im going to look into ffmpeg because it looks like it is a great tool that might be a good clue.